# Trying to write a post request to create a database with fiber and gorm and it gives me an error

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-fiber

*trying to oupt a post (create) request using gorm as my database and fiber as my golang framewor but it seems like it is not working sometimes it returns "json: unmarshal(non-pointer, main.AcctDetails)" someone should please help me out i have been stuck here for quite a long time*

```
package main

import (

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

var (
    DB  *gorm.DB
    err error
)

type AcctDetails struct {
        gorm.Model
        ID           uint    `json:"id"`
        AcctName     string  `json:"acctname"`
        AcctNumber   string  `json:"acctnumber"`
        UsersPhoneNo string  `json:"usersphoneno"`
    }


func Routers(app *fiber.App) {
    app.Post("/bank", CreateUser)
}

func CreateUser(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    info := new(AcctDetails)
    
    if err := c.BodyParser(info); err != nil {
        return c.Status(500).SendString(err.Error())
    }

    DB.Create(&info)
    return c.Status(200).JSON(&info)
}

func main() {
    app := fiber.New()
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("Cannot Connect To Database")
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&AcctDetails{})
    Routers(app)
    app.Listen(":3000")
}
```

and it returns this as error

```
PS C:\Users\Chinonso\Desktop\New folder\GO\main> go run main.go

2022/04/29 22:47:51 C:/Users/Chinonso/Desktop/New folder/GO/main/main.go:45 SLOW SQL >= 200ms
[272.120ms] [rows:0] CREATE TABLE `acct_details` (`id` integer,`created_at` datetime,`updated_at` datetime,`deleted_at` datetime,`acct_name` text,`acct_number` text,`users_phone_no` text,PRIMARY KEY (`id`))

*this is after the server starts*

panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0x7ff7bc6f05a2]

goroutine 8 [running]:
gorm.io/gorm.(*DB).Create(0xc0000c0000, {0x7ff7bc92e820, 0xc0000b4010})
        C:/Users/Chinonso/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.23.5/finisher_api.go:18 +0x22
main.CreateUser(0xc0000c0000)
        C:/Users/Chinonso/Desktop/New folder/GO/main/main.go:35 +0xe5
github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2.(*App).next(0xc0000023c0, 0xc0000c0000)
        C:/Users/Chinonso/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2@v2.32.0/router.go:132 +0x1be
github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2.(*App).handler(0xc0000023c0, 0x7ff7bc3a19b7)
        C:/Users/Chinonso/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2@v2.32.0/router.go:159 +0x45
github.com/valyala/fasthttp.(*Server).serveConn(0xc000127440, {0x7ff7bca94f30, 0xc000006ef8})
        C:/Users/Chinonso/go/pkg/mod/github.com/valyala/fasthttp@v1.35.0/server.go:2338 +0x11ae
github.com/valyala/fasthttp.(*workerPool).workerFunc(0xc0002a9360, 0xc0002bd440)
        C:/Users/Chinonso/go/pkg/mod/github.com/valyala/fasthttp@v1.35.0/workerpool.go:224 +0xa9
github.com/valyala/fasthttp.(*workerPool).getCh.func1()
        C:/Users/Chinonso/go/pkg/mod/github.com/valyala/fasthttp@v1.35.0/workerpool.go:196 +0x38
created by github.com/valyala/fasthttp.(*workerPool).getCh
        C:/Users/Chinonso/go/pkg/mod/github.com/valyala/fasthttp@v1.35.0/workerpool.go:195 +0x1b5
exit status 2
PS C:\Users\Chinonso\Desktop\New folder\GO\main>
```

please someone should help me resolve this code it's giving me headach since two months now.

Comment: why the git tag ?

Comment: Please next time consider using debugger before asking question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `DB.Create()` but didn't assign `db` to global variable `DB`.
*Note: using debugger could prevent a lot of headaches*

### Before

```golang
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})
```

### After

```golang
    DB, err = gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})
```